# ActiveMQ broker to connect to Tibco EMS over SSL

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Im trying to setup a broker between ActiveMQ and Tibco EMS with SSL Connectivity.

1. I have copied jms-2.0.jar, tibcrypt.jar, tibjms.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar under activemq/lib
2. I have following activemq.xml config

**Issue:** Broker starts fine. However its not able to capture New messages from EMS. neither it raises any error.

> ```
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>   http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
>     <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
>     <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
>         <property name="locations">
>             <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
>         </property>
>     </bean>
>    <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
>     <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
>           lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
>           init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
>     </bean>
>  <!-- JMS ConnectionFactory to use for local bridging -->
>     <bean id="tibco" class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory">
>         <property name="serverUrl" value="ssl://10.88.66.225:7243" />
>   <property name="userName" value="admin" />
>   <property name="userPassword" value="admin123" />
>   <property name="SSLIdentity" value="/home/activemq/activemq/conf/client_identity.p12" />
>   <property name="SSLAuthOnly" value="true" />
>     </bean>
>     <!--
>         The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
>     -->
>     <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
>         <destinationPolicy>
>             <policyMap>
>               <policyEntries>
>                 <policyEntry topic=">" >
>                     <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
>                          slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
>                          by limiting the number of messages that are retained
>                          For more information, see:
>                          http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html
>                     -->
>                   <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
>                     <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
>                   </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
>                 </policyEntry>
>               </policyEntries>
>             </policyMap>
>         </destinationPolicy>
>         <!--
>             The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
>             JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
>             the JVM. For more information, see:
>             http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
>         -->
>         <managementContext>
>             <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
>         </managementContext>
>         <!--
>             Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
>             mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
>             For more information, see:
>             http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
>         -->
>         <persistenceAdapter>
>             <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
>         </persistenceAdapter>
>           <!--
>             The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
>             use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
>             http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
>           -->
>           <systemUsage>
>             <systemUsage>
>                 <memoryUsage>
>                     <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
>                 </memoryUsage>
>                 <storeUsage>
>                     <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
>                 </storeUsage>
>                 <tempUsage>
>                     <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
>                 </tempUsage>
>             </systemUsage>
>         </systemUsage>
>         <!--
>             The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
>             clients and other brokers. For more information, see:
>             http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
>         -->
>         <transportConnectors>
>             <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
>             <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
>             <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
>             <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
>             <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
>             <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
>         </transportConnectors>
>         <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
>         <shutdownHooks>
>             <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
> ```
>
> class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
>
> ```
>         <!-- Dependencies: tibjms.jar must be in the activemq lib directory -->
>         <!-- bridging definitions for traffic to/from remote activemq instance -->
>         <jmsBridgeConnectors>
>             <jmsQueueConnector outboundQueueConnectionFactory="#tibco">
>                 <inboundQueueBridges>
>                     <inboundQueueBridge
>                             inboundQueueName = "queue.Sample"
>                             localQueueName   = "queue.incomingMsgs.Sample"/>
>                 </inboundQueueBridges>
>                 <outboundQueueBridges>
>                     <outboundQueueBridge
>                             outboundQueueName = "queue.activemqtoems"
>                             localQueueName    = "queue.incomingMsgs.Sample"/>
>                  </outboundQueueBridges>
>             </jmsQueueConnector>
>         </jmsBridgeConnectors>
>     </broker>
>
>     <!--
>         Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
>         The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file
>         Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
>     -->
>     <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
> </beans>
> <!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using a bridge instead of wiring up broker-to-broker JMS with ActiveMQ. The broker-to-broker approach is complicated by error handling scenarios, which a bridge can be better customized to handle for your use case.